# contextual menu preferences on mac os x (without code injection)

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

By default all services comes in lower part of contextual menu.

[image]

Is there any way to move my service `MyfolderSelect` up (above the Move to Trash)? I am on 10.6.8 OS X server.

Comment: As @Wevah said, it cannot be done. You are not allowed direct access to Finder's contextual menus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not without injecting code into the Finder. Services will always appear at the bottom of the menu.